# Can i construct a linked list with curly braces?

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list, curly-braces

I am fairly new to object oriented C++, and I'm trying to make a constructor for a linked list in this way:

Somewhere in the List.h we'd have this:

```
struct Node
{   
    int data;
    Node *next;
};
```

and then in the main.cpp, I'd like to be able to construct a list like this:

```
int main()
{
List A({1,2,3,4,5,6});// I want the amount of numbers to indicate the size of
 //the list and the numbers to go into each node in order
return 0;    
}
```

So my question is, can i make such a constructor? If so then how? Do i have to use templates do this? I tried to find a question like this answered in SO but they all included templates and i haven't learned that yet. If i can make my constructor to do this, is it possible to do it without using templates?

Comment: I think this is possible in C++11.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

Comment: @payo and that would be a *template*.

Comment: `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` is an array so if you make a constructor that takes an array and creates the list that should work.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah No, it isn't. That's an initializer list, but definitely not an array.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Even if it were an array (which it isn't without a cast-immediate such as `(int const []){1,2,3,4,5,6}`) I'm curious how you would bring the *magnitude* of the array into the mix without an additional parameter or a non-type template param like `template<size_t N> List(int const(&ar)[N])`.

Comment: Apparently "is it possible to do it without using templates?" means different things to different people. I completely concur the way to do this from sanity point is `std::initializer_list<>`, but I forwent posting such a solution to comply with the OP's closing question. Not sure if that is how it was meant to be taken (and apparently others *are* fairly sure it *wasn't*) but that was how I saw it. Sans-*all*-templates is the only thing that make this question interesting; otherwise its trivial.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right you are.  g++ accepts it but only with -std=c++11 so I must have misread the question.  My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this (using C++11).

You need to define a constructor taking an `std::initializer_list<int>`. 
(Yes this is a template, but I will show you how to use it. :-) )

A possible implementation of an `std::intitializer_list<int>`-constructor could look like this:

```
//in class List:
List (std::initializer_list<int> init) {
    for (auto v : init)
        this->emplace_back(v);
}
```

where you have to implement `emplace_back` yourself as an exercise. `emplace_back` should construct a new `Node` and append it to the `List`. It will be a useful member function (I promise).

Probably unimportant notice:
If `emplace_back` does heap allocations, this code might leak. In this case, delegate to a constructor that puts the `List` into a valid state, so the destructor can free all the heap-allocated `Nodes`.
If you do not understand this, it is most likely not too important for your application.

Comment: Just noticed: the `this->` is redundant, but won't hurt.

Comment: Nice. For production-quality code, it is good to mention that strong exception guarantee is desirable for such a constructor. That is, similarly to [std::uninitialized_copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy), if `emplace_back` throws, then all previously constructed objects must be destructed/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`. See an example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list

Answer (score 0):

not really.  I believe the declaration of the number list in curly braces will confuse the compiler.  Better to declare an int array and pass it to a constructor that takes an int array and a size variable   Consider the following:

```
int aray[] = {5,6,11,22,11};
int size   = sizeof(aray)/sizeof(int);

MyList(size,aray);
```